# How to save the results of a query on variables for each field on Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, web-services, arraylist

I need to accomplish the following:

1.- Save on different variables each field of a query result (Oracle DB).
The query result could be 1 o more rows (5 average).
2.- Invoke a WebService for each row.
4.- Wait for the WebService answer and then repeat the process.

I think that saving the result of 1 row and then invoke the WebService it easy but the problem is when the query result throws more than 1 row.

How can I do this? Is Arraylist the answer?

EDIT: I am using the following code. How can I print the arraylist to see if the connection is working?
If I run this i get:

```
com.packagename.SomeBean@1d251891
com.packagename.SomeBean@48140564
com.packagename.SomeBean@58ceff1
```

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

List<SomeBean> v = new ArrayList<SomeBean>();

String query = "select * from table where ROWNUM BETWEEN 1 and 3";

try 
{
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:user/pass@localhost:port:SID");
      stmt = con.createStatement();     
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  while( rs.next() ){             

    SomeBean n = new SomeBean();
    n.setColumn1(rs.getInt("column1"));
    n.setColumn2(rs.getString("column2"));
    n.setColumn3(rs.getString("column3"));
    n.setColumn4(rs.getInt("column4"));
    n.setColumn5(rs.getString("column5"));
    n.setColumn6(rs.getString("column6"));
    n.setColumn7(rs.getString("column7"));
    ...
    v.add(n);       
    }

  for(SomeBean s : v){
    System.out.println(s);
  }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your question is quite difficoult. 
But I can give you some hints.

Your startpoint is JDBC.

> The Java Database Connectivity (JDBC)
>
> The Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) API is the industry standard for database-independent connectivity between the Java programming language and a wide range of databases  SQL databases and other tabular data sources, such as spreadsheets or flat files. The JDBC API provides a call-level API for SQL-based database access.
>
> [The Java Database Connectivity (JDBC)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html)

Once you are able to establish a connection to the DB, this snippet can help you answering to your question.

```
    // start connection
    List<SomeBean> v = new ArrayList<SomeBean>();
    Statement st;
    try 
    {
        st = conn.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);        
        while( rs.next() ){             

                SomeBean n = new SomeBean();
                n.setFirstField(rs.getInt("firstfield"));
                n.setSecondField(rs.getString("secondfield"));

                ...
                ...

                v.add(n);
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // close connection
```

Once you have your collection of beans, just write a for loop that calls the webservice one time for each bean.

```
    for(SomeBean s : v){

            callToYouWS(s);

    }
```

Comment: I already figure it out the connection to the DB. I have arraylist issues. Your snippet will be very useful. Thanks a lot. @giuseppe-marra

Comment: I am using the code you posted. But I don't know how to print the arraylist. How can I print the arraylist? Sorry, I am a n00b. I added the code in question.

Comment: You need to overrite the `toString()` of your object if you want to print object like that.

Comment: I did it, getting each column like this: `System.out.println(s.getColumn1())`

Comment: Well done! For the future,  the `Object` class provides a method `toString()` that is designed to return a string representation of the object. However, each class has to override it with its own logic. When you see strings like `com.packagename.SomeBean@58ceff1` it means that you are using the default implementation of the `toString()` method that returns you just an identifier.